# Parse Push not working on emulator

Tags: android

I'm currently using Parse Push for android, I used the tutorial provided and managed to receive it on the real device, but my emulator does not receive it. I do not think it is a coding problem.. I checked the app at parse push and there are 2 subscribers, one the real device and the other the emulator

Comment: you shouldn't be using emulator for testing pushes. They don't work quite well with that. If device is receiving pushes, your code works fine.

Comment: push are receive. in real device..

Answer (score 0):

Push is not shown on emulator 
and if you want to parse push
try this ,

```
public static String bundle2string(Bundle bundle) {
        String string = "{";
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            string += " " + key + " => " + bundle.get(key) + ";";
        }
        string += " }";
        return string;
    }
```